# Dynamic select boxes based on previous choice

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, html-select

I want to have on my site a single `select` box that will then populate new `select` boxes depending on what is chosen.

Say, if the user chooses "cat", then a new `select` box will appear with breeds of cats, or if they choose "dog", then a new `select` box will appear with a list of breeds of dogs. But before they choose either "dog" or "cat", then the second box will not exist.

Is there any way I can do this with CSS/HTML only, or do I HAVE to use javascript?

If I can do it with CSS/HTML only, please provide an example or link. If I have to use javascript, I do not need an example, just to be told that I have to use it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Yes you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: you have to use javascript if you want to manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use javascript.  You cannot make ccs rules based on selections from a `select`.